# How can I add spacing between numbers in number picker?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to add some spacing between the numbers in my NumberPicker because as I increase the text size the number starts overlapping each other and it doesn't look very good. Below is the picture of what it currently looks like. I would like to Increase the size so you can see the number above and below the currently selected number. Is this even possible when using a NumberPicker?

[image]

Here is the Kotlin Code I have that create the above UI:

```
     speed.setOnClickListener {
                val dialog = NumberPicker(this)
                dialog.minValue = 1
                dialog.maxValue = 200
                dialog.value = targetTime.toInt()
                dialog.wrapSelectorWheel = false
                dialog.textColor = Color.WHITE // Set the text color to white
                dialog.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK) // Set the background color to black
    
                val screenHeight = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
                val pickerHeight = (screenHeight * 0.9).toInt()
    
                val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    pickerHeight
                )
    
                dialog.setOnValueChangedListener { _, _, newVal ->
                    targetTime = newVal.toDouble()
                }
    
                dialog.layoutParams = lp
    
                val title = TextView(this).apply {
                    text = "Select Target Speed (mph)"
                    textSize = 30f // Set the text size of the title
                    setTextColor(Color.WHITE) // Set the text color to white
                    gravity = Gravity.CENTER // Center the title text
                }
    
                val alertDialog: AlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setCustomTitle(title) // Set the customized title
                    .setView(dialog)
                    .setPos

itiveButton("SET", null)
                .create()

            alertDialog.show()

            alertDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK))
            alertDialog.window?.setLayout(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            ) // Set the dialog window to take up the entire screen

            val positiveButton = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)

            // Set layout parameters for the positive button
            val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )

            // Set the gravity of the button to center and set the margins
            layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            layoutParams.setMargins(430, 10, 430, 10) // Set the margins (left, top, right, bottom)

            // Set the layout parameters of the positive button
            positiveButton.layoutParams = layoutParams

            positiveButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            positiveButton.setBackgroundColor(parseColor("#FFE222"))
            positiveButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 40f) // Set the text size of the positive button
        }
```

I also have this XML that does some styling for the numberPicker:

```
<item name="android:textSize">80sp</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
class SpacedNumberPicker @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : NumberPicker(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val spacing: Int = (textSize * 0.25f).toInt()
    private val textPaint: Paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = currentTextColor
        textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        textSize = this@SpacedNumberPicker.textSize
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        canvas?.let {
            val x = width / 2f
            val y = height / 2f

            it.drawText(" ", x, y - spacing, textPaint)
            it.drawText(" ", x, y + spacing, textPaint)
        }
    }
}
```

The `SpacedNumberPicker` class is a custom implementation of the `NumberPicker` view in `Android` that adds spacing between its numbers. Here are the key features of this implementation:

- The constructor uses the @JvmOverloads annotation to avoid boilerplate code for the constructor overloads.
- The spacing property is calculated based on the textSize property of the view and set to 25% of its value. This spacing is used to add space between the numbers while drawing.
- The `textPaint` property is a Paint object that is used to draw the text on the canvas. It's initialized with anti-aliasing, the current text color, center alignment, and the textSize property of the view.
- The `onDraw()` method is overridden to draw the additional space between the numbers. It first calls the `super.onDraw()` method to draw the default numbers, then it retrieves the canvas object and checks if it's not null before proceeding.
- The `x` and `y` positions of the center of the view are calculated using the width and height properties, respectively. The `drawText()` method is then called twice to draw a space above and below the numbers using the textPaint object.

PD: I didn't test the code myself but that should give you a start.